# How to prevent those PHP variables from being cached on WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using this code in functions.php on WordPress to generate an affiliate link based on the visitor location, It's working perfectly but the problem is that if page caching is turned on (W3 Total Cache), The variables get cached so if someone from the UK was the first one to open the page then the second one from Germany opened the page he will get the same link that the first visitor got.

One more thing please, I'm still very new to PHP and javascript so I would appreciate if the answer was simplified enough

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'affiliate_link', 10);

function affiliate_link() { 
    $not_avilable_country = '<div id="amz_not_avilable" class="amz_not_avilable">This product is not avilable in your country yet</div>';

    // IP Geolocation   
    $country_code = $_SERVER ["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];
    // Get Custom Fields
    $de_asin = get_post_meta(get_post()->ID, "wccaf_de_asin", true );
    $uk_asin = get_post_meta(get_post()->ID, "wccaf_uk_asin", true );

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    if ($country_code=="DE" or $country_code=="DE") {
        $amazon_domain = 'https://www.amazon.de';
     // $associate_id = 'bonstato-21';
        $asin = $de_asin;
    }

    else if ($country_code=="GB" && $uk_asin!=="") {
        $amazon_domain = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk';
     // $associate_id = 'bonmedico-21';
        $asin = $uk_asin;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    if( wp_is_mobile() ) {

    // Amazon Link For Mobile       
    ?>
    <script>
    function amzGo(){
        window.location='<?php echo $amazon_domain ?>/dp/<?php echo $asin ?>/?tag=<?php echo $associate_id ?>';
    }
    </script>
    <?php

    } else {

    // Amazon Link For PC
    ?>
    <script>
    function amzGo(){
        window.location='<?php echo $amazon_domain ?>/gp/aws/cart/add.html?AssociateTag=<?php echo $associate_id ?>&ASIN.1=<?php echo $asin ?>&Quantity.1=1';
    }
    </script>
    <?php
    }

    ?>
    <div class="buy_amz_btn_wrap" >  
        <button type="button" id="buy_amz_btn" class="buy_amz_btn" onclick="amzGo();"><i class="fa fa-amazon fa-amz"></i><?php echo $amz_btn_title ?></button>                           
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but you could try to set some initial values for the variables and a timestamp and after to use an if statement to check if current timestamp is greater than initial one and inside the {} to set the variables.